# The probability that the opponent will win the battle

Tags: probability

Two people are fighting: each one in his turn is shooting one shot, the game is over when one gets a hit, the probabilitiy that the first person (that shot first) will hit in his opponent in a shot is $0.6$, the probabilitiy second  person will hit in his opponent in a shot is $0.8$

> - Find the probability for each one of the two opponents to win
> - Find the distribution of the number of shots in a battle

---

I am thinking that it somehow related to goemtric distribution, for the first pesron something like this $X\sim G(0.6)$ and for the second person something like this $X\sim G(0.4)$but how can I find the probabilitis? because if I'm right so the probability that the first person will win will be $P(X=k)=0.6(1-0.6)^{k-1}$ and this is not a number.

any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can say that the probability of the first person winning is the probability of ending the battle lasting for an odd number of rounds. Looking at two seperate distributions is imho not realy helpful here because one opponent cannot have 6 attempts if the other one succedes at the second. So what is the probability of person A winning?

Person A wins if the battle ends after an odd number of rounds. How do we compute the probability of a certain number of rounds? It is a concatenation of independent events, so for the battle to last 1 round, we have 0.6 (success at the first attempt). For k failures for both parties and then a success for person A we have:
$(1-0.6)^k\cdot (1-0.8)^k \cdot 0.6$
So you are right, it is related to the geometric distribution, but you have to combine the probability of each one failing k times.

Now you want the probability of Person A winning, no matter after how many rounds. You have to compute the sum 
$\sum_{k=1}^\infty(1-0.6)^k\cdot (1-0.8)^k \cdot 0.6$ .